# How to get value from INPUT filed and pass it to jQuery var on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Dudes! I've a POST form one field of this is:

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

In jQuery I placed var called **var username** = <---code here--->;

The question is how to ***interactively pass the INPUT field value to this var*** before user hit the **Submit button**?

Comment: You might have to show us your code, too.

Comment: Piece of JQuery for the from, in real I want to dynamically change action URL as user typing. $('.quick-login-form').attr('action','http://' + window.document.location.hostname + appname + **username**);

Comment: If I write like var username = example; Than the url is ..example at the end. Unfortunately, I still cannot bypass it from the input field.

Comment: Trying this var username = document.getElementById("username").nodeValue;   the result is NUL

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("input[name='username']").blur(function() {
  var username = $(this).val();
});
```

Do you mean something like this

Comment: Yeah, probably. Now the var is [object HTMLInputElement] maybe add some more parameters? The form also provided by jQuery. Specify start of the behavior like "Change"?

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery selector that will find that field is:

```
var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
```

To assign the variable before the form is submitted, you could follow Sudhir's answer, or capture it when the form is submitted:

```
$(function() {
    $('#yourFormid').submit(function() {
        var username = $('input[name="username"]', this).val();
        // do work
        return true; // true to submit the form, false to cancel submission
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that updates the variable as the user types.

A live demo can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/EnS8T/11/

```
var username = "";
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("[name='username']").keyup(function()
    {
        username = $(this).val();     
    });

});
```

Other functions, besides [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), that can be used include [keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) and [keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/). The behavior of these three functions can be observed in the jsFiddle above.

Comment: @PranavKapoor thanks, I've improved my fiddle based on your demo.

Answer (score 0):

By interactively, do you mean as typed? Then use onKeyPress event on your textbox. You might have to do something strange, like create a setTimeout, if you don't want to write a lot of code to monitor cursor position.

Comment: Yes, it is. I new to JAVA so cannot clarify what specific code should be );

Comment: Telmo Marques answer contains an example of what I was talking about. He is using onKeyUp instead of onKeyPress, which has some advantages, but also some disadvantages as well (as in if you press the letter and don't let go of the button, it's not going to register until you let go).